In Postgres SET value is accessible in all sessions
I tried to set variable "my.tenant" in one session but same variable value persist in all sessions.
SET my.tenant=2
SHOW my.tenant

If i open another session in postgres i am getting value for SHOW my.tenant.
In all other Database session working correctly but in my database it behaves different.
What will be the cause? My Postgres Version - 13.4

That’s a runtime server configuration thing


Postgres 13 is currently at minor release .15, I would suggest updating. 2)  Per SET a manual SET like this is session specific. My guess is you have something else setting this, maybe ALTER DATABASE ... SET configuration_parameter =  value 


A SET in one session will never influence another session. Perhaps you are using a connection pooler.
